# JBoss Fuse - Maven Archetype Blueprint - Camel - Routing

Tags: java, maven, jboss, apache-camel, blueprint

I am trying to build a simple `Camel` route using `JBoss Fuse` and `Maven` basically. I am using the command `mvn archetype:generate` to create a skeleton project.

When the prompt says, "Choose a number or apply filter (format: [groupId:]artifactId, case sensitive contains): 582:" I type `camel`.

Then I select this option: `49: remote -> org.apache.camel.archetypes:camel-archetype-blueprint (Creates a new Camel project with OSGi blueprint support. Ready to be deployed in OSGi.)`

Please see below:

`Choose a number or apply filter (format: [groupId:]artifactId, case sensitive contains): :` I type `49` for this option.

For the option `Choose org.apache.camel.archetypes:camel-archetype-blueprint version:` I press enter for Camel 2.15.1.

`Define value for property 'groupId': :` org.me

For the option: 
`Define value for property 'artifactId': :` fuse-ghettoblasting-blueprint

For the option:
`Define value for property 'version':  1.0-SNAPSHOT: :` 1.0

For the option:
`Define value for property 'package':  org.me: :` org.me.demo

I run this command `mvn clean install` to install the pom.xml and the jar to my local Maven repository.

I then go to the JBoss Fuse console and type:

`JBossFuse:karaf@root> osgi:install mvn:org.me/fuse-ghettoblasting-blueprint/1.0`

Then I receive a bundle ID: 
`Bundle ID: 389`

When I type`JBossFuse:karaf@root> list`
I see the bundle but it says `Failure` in the Blueprint field as shown below: 
   ID     State        Blueprint       Spring   Level  Name
`[ 389] [Active     ] [Failure     ] [       ] [   60] Camel Blueprint Route (1.0.0)

I had a similar experience when running through this tutorial: https://codevomit.wordpress.com/2014/12/24/simple-camel-route-in-jboss-fuse/

This tutorial involved actually creating routes in the ActiveMQ interface on the localhost running at port 8181

Is there an expert out there reading this that knows what I am missing? Why is the Blueprint failing? Why is the Message sent from the Queue not logged as shown in the tutorial from CodeVomit?

Regards,

*UPDATE*

Here is my source code for the blueprint.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd">


<!-- connect to the local ActiveMQ broker -->
<bean id="activemq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
  <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://localhost:61616" />
  <property name="userName" value="user123" />
  <property name="password" value="user123" />
  <property></property>
</bean>

  <camelContext id="blueprintContext" trace="false" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">

    <route id="queue2queue">
        <from uri="activemq://source-queue" />
        <log message="the message body is: ${body}" loggingLevel="INFO" />
        <to uri="activemq://sink-queue" />
    </route>



  </camelContext>

</blueprint>
```

Comment: If you want to connect to the local broker, you can omit the "activemq" declaration. There is an example in JBoss Fuse 6.1, see under quickstarts - there is the JMS example that uses ActiveMQ + Camel.

Comment: When you write the "'activemq' declaration" do you mean in the `<to>` and `<from>` elements inside the `<route>` element? Thank-you for the helpful reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the same version of Apache Camel as JBoss Fuse supports/ships with. Camel 2.15.x is not yet supported this requires the upcoming JBoss Fuse 6.2 release.

You can use Fuse IDE tooling to create a Fuse project that uses the correct version of Camel.

- http://www.jboss.org/products/devstudio/download/

An alternative is to adjust the `pom.xml` which which the archetype generted, to the same Camel version that Fuse ships. You can find the Camel version from the Fuse shell by typing `list` and find the `camel-core` line that should print the version.

Comment: I tried your 'alternative' method since the learning curve of the Fuse IDE is quite daunting and I still receive that the Blueprint is [Failure] upon starting the bundle. Thank-you for taking a guess at what is going wrong with my program though Claus. :D

Comment: You can try look in the log file, in data/logs/fuse.log file. Or use log:display from the shell - the latter only shows 1000 lines back (I think)

Comment: It works when copying a cfg.xml file mentioned in the 'jms' quickstart to the etc folder and removing the bean element with the `id=activemq`. :) Thank-you for the help. Maybe mention this in your answer for some solid help for some poor confused programmer flipping out? :D